# How many 12/2g can I run through a 2-1/2 inch chase nipple?

Tags: wiring

I am upgrading a recessed panel plus adding cables to the box in the enclosed stud cavity. There are not enough knockouts in the panel box to accommodate entrance of all the cables so I propose cutting in two 2-1/2 inch Chase nipples. Is that allowable?

Comment: To address the question directly - Why not just use duplex connectors, it seems so much easier and how will you provide strain relief with chase nipples?

Comment: To broaden the question - If there are literally not enough knockouts for your cables, there are probably not enough of multiple other important resources for them either.  Spaces, breakers, etc.  Please give more info on the full situation.  If the problem is there are not enough *on the side where you want them*, probably the top, then where will you cut the holes?  A photo of the entire situation would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, how are you going to strain relief the cable jackets?

Comment: Also, please [edit] to ensure your title question lines up with the question you're asking in the body. As it stands, you're asking to totally different questions.